# Sum of a recursive series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

Find $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{x} a_{k}$ , where $a_1 = 1$ and $\forall k>1 : a_{k}=a_{k-1}+{\lfloor \sqrt {a_{k-1}} \rfloor} $ and $x$ is a natural number such that $a_{x} \leq n < a_{x+1}$. For simply the sequence $a_k$ is $\{1,2,3,4,6,8,10,13,16,20,24,28,33,38,44,…\}$. Similarly the sequence $S_n$ is $\{1,3,6,10,10,16,16,24,24,34,34,34,47,…\}$

I tried to bound it by some other familiar summations without any success of a tight one. I think there is no need for a close expression.
It can be proved that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist $K$ such that for all $k>K$ : $a_k < k^{1+\epsilon}$, but it seemingly not provide the necessary. I think the point is to focus on the distance between the elements in the sequence that getting bigger. Let also notice that we have the arithmetic sequence $\{1,2,3,4,…\}$ which definitely more dense and therefore it is clear that $S_{n}\leq c \cdot n^2$ for some real $c$ , but I think that there exist $c_1,c_2$ real numbers that
$c_1\cdot n\cdot \sqrt {n}\leq S_{n}\leq c_2\cdot n\cdot \sqrt {n}$.

If we write the sequence brute force we can see that $S_{n} \geq\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor} k^2 \geq \frac{1}{3} \cdot n\cdot \sqrt {n} $. Also it seemed that for all $n>16$ : $S_n \leq n\cdot \sqrt {n}$ and even for every $n \geq 1 :  S_n \leq 3 n\cdot \sqrt {n}$.  Any suggestion for a formal lower and upper bound ? Or maybe suggestion for a close expression of $a_k$ such that we can bound $S_n$ by integration.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002984 is the OIES for this sequence. It provides some quadratic bounds, but seemingly no bounds of the form you suggest. Also there are no closed formulae listed.

Comment: At $n>3$: $n+\frac23 n^{\frac32} < S_n < \frac52 n+\frac23 n^{\frac32}$.